# Error Empty Response(in chrome) when working with sessions

Tags: php, jquery, session

I am quite confused with this problem. Once in while, When I try to open my admin pages *(written in **PHP** and using **jQuery**)* in which I've used sessions to handle logins.

**Chrome reports**

```
324 error (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)
```

Changing browsers or clearing cache and cookies does not work, but error resolves when I restart apache and sql using `service httpd restart` and `service mysqld restart` but this doesn't help either, since I'm not able to do this every time.

**UPDATE:** This is the part of my code handling sessions.

```
<?php
//Set no caching
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/moshaver/css/all.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/moshaver/css/index.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/moshaver/css/main.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<?php
require "Connect.php";
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');

if(isset($_GET['scroll'])){
  $scroll= $_GET['scroll'];
}
$req= require 'retail/passwordLib.php';
if (!$req){
  echo "file not found";
}
if(!isset($_SESSION["Logined"])){
  $username = $_POST[ 'username' ];
  $password = $_POST[ 'password' ];

if(!$db){
  die('oops, something went wrong!');
}else{
  $result3 = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM login WHERE user=:username');
  $result3->bindParam(':username',$username);
  $result3->execute();
  $row = $result3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $hash= $row['pass'];
  $user= $row['user'];
}

if( !$username == $user || !password_verify($password, $hash)){
session_start();
$_SESSION["Login.Error"] = '<h5>نام کاربری یا گذرواژه صحیح نیست! </h5>';//redirect back to your login page]
          header('location:../index.php');
     }
  else {
     $_SESSION["Logined"]=$username;
  }}else{};
?>
```

Comment: Please send code and exception so we can help

Comment: @AhmadRezk I added the code and chrome error message. Is there anything else I could add?

Comment: * Your code need restructure
* Why you write this condition  `!$username == $user` like this, why `!$username` ??
* Try to put your PHP code first on the top of the page then write your html

Comment: @AhmadRezk Oh my mistake, you're right. Thanks for your help but unfortunately the problem still exists.